# Configuring MongoDB on Windows

Tags: mongodb, configuration

I am trying to set up MongoDB on Windows, and the online docs seem far from accurate.

Under "Configure a Windows Service" part, [step 1](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-directories-and-files) mentions to create a config file. Then it mentions to fill in the file with a line in the format `logpath="X:\path\mongo.log"`. However, following the link, the config file is said to be in YAML format, which renders the previous line unreadable in YAML.

I have created a basic `mongodb.cfg`(`.cfg` or `.conf`??) file:

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "P:\\Servers\\MongoDB\\logs\\mongodb.log"
   quiet: true
   logAppend: true
storage:
   dbPath: "P:\\Servers\\MongoDB\\data"
   journal:
      enabled: true
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017
```

However when I start `mongod --config P:\Servers\MongoDB\mongodb.cfg`, the service just won't give any output at all, and just hangs.

If I remove the `dbPath` line, it will just close itself with no message at all.

I have also tried to leave the `mongodb.cfg` file just like this:

```
logpath="P:\Servers\MongoDB\logs\mongodb.log"
dbpath="P:\Servers\MongoDB\data"
```

But execution aborts complaining about any of the 2 paths, even tho they exist. Tried with single backslashes and with escaped backslashes (`\\`) with no success.

The only way the service works and listens for connections is to manually pass `--dbpath` only, and **ignore any config file and logpath** at all. Obviously this is not serious, as I need to keep track of the logs and also might need to change config parameters at some later point.

This is nuts... Am I missing something very basic or this docs are a real mess?

Comment: I guess the problem is with systemlog configuration. bcuz if you ignor configuring logpath parameters, it will run nicely

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is my simple test MongoDB Config file for Windows. Note that I had to have 2 spaces before each property, e.g., path. When I had 3 spaces I got an error at startup.

I start the server with: `mongod --config c:\tools\mongodb\db\mongod.cfg`

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "C:\\tools\\mongodb\\db\\log\\mongo.log"
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: "C:\\tools\\mongodb\\db\\data"
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Comment: I had issues with more than 2 blank spaces on the 2nd, 3rd lines and got an error at startup. After fixing it worked perfectly.

Comment: This is very helpful :) I forgot to put 2nd /.. and 2 blank spaces. Coming from ubuntu environment to windows is nightmare :D

Answer (score 5):

For those who installed via *.msi installer and wondering where is .conf file located. Run 'services.msc' and check properties of mongodb service runnable file.

there is a 'Path to executable' like:

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongod.exe" --config    "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongod.cfg" --service
```

so the config file is:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin\mongod.cfg
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of a mongodb.config file for Windows.

```
##store data here
dbpath=C:\mongodb\data\db

##all output go here
logpath=C:\mongodb\data\log\mongo.log

##log read and write operations
diaglog=3
```

Answer (score 2):

Bit late but I had the exact same issue today. If you use forward slashes for your paths within the config file it works fine.

`systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: "e:/mongo_data/3.6/mongo.log"
storage:
  dbPath: "e:/mongo_data/3.6/db"
  engine: "wiredTiger"`

Answer (score 1):

check if you have any file in data\db path. Please remove all those files and try to restart. I exactly used your config file and able to start the service successfully with bindip and port

Answer (score 0):

You can find logs with reasons why it's not working in log file. In your case, read P:\Servers\MongoDB\logs\mongodb.log file.

Answer (score 0):

For window user it's stored here,

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin

if you are not able to find this, then verify that is your service running or not!