# MongoDB minidump file path is wrong

Tags: mongodb, configuration, path, minidump

I recently uninstalled MongoDB 3.2 to install MongoDB 3.6. Since then, every time I try to launch mongod, I get the following error: `failed to open minidump file C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2018-02-18T17-02-35.mdmp : Access is denied`.

I'm not even quite sure why it says `Access is denied` because, as I mentioned, I uninstalled MongoDB 3.2 hence the server/3.2/ directory doesn't exist anymore. So is there a way to change where MongoDB looks for this file?

Also, notice how the path seems to be missing a slash right after 3.2...... It does appear like that in my terminal, it's not a typo, I'm not sure about what I should think of that.

I am running Windows 10. And I want to point out that I did use the MongoDB 'wizard' to uninstall version 3.2 of MongoDB.

---

**EDIT**: I decided to wipe all of my database data folder and seed back the database and for now it seems to be working fine but I'll leave the question open until we can find a definitive answer to the problem, if possible

Comment: How are you starting MongoDB: are you running `mongod.exe` with command line options, or starting as a Windows service? Did you stop the MongoDB 3.2 server before uninstalling?

Comment: Also note that the supported upgrade path from MongoDB 3.2 => 3.6 is to upgrade to MongoDB 3.4 first. See: [Upgrade a Standalone to 3.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-upgrade-standalone/#upgrade-version-path). The consequences of skipping one or more major releases will depend on your configuration and compatibility changes between successive releases, but it's generally best to follow the supported (and tested) upgrade procedures. You should also take a full backup of your data prior to any upgrades in case you run into any unexpected challenges.

Comment: @Stennie I am launching mongod from a terminal with command line options. I did stop the MongoDB 3.2 server correctly before uninstalling.

Comment: @Stennie I wasn't aware of a specific upgrade path and I skipped straight from 3.2 to 3.6. That might have been the cause of the problem. I decided to wipe my database (I'm still in dev so no worries)  and just seed it again and at least for now it seems to be working fine. I guess I'll leave the question open to see if I can find a definitive answer to the problem.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with a project which was working fine for me until then.

I used the following command and everything went back to normal:

```
mongod --dbpath "path" --repair
```

Comment: I had a similar problem when I moved the database folder from one machine to another. This one worked out for me!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the mongod.conf file to find out the dbpath. If the path is correct, update the folder permissions to give the mongodb user the required permissions in Control Panel. I am sorry that I don't have Microsoft System to find out the location of the mongod.conf file.

The usual path for Ubuntu system is /etc/mongod.conf and in the case of Mac it is /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf and you can edit using the command if you want to change the path.

```
sudo nano /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

[image: Look at the dbpath under the storage]

In the case of Ubuntu or Linux or Mac the following command can be given.

```
 sudo chown -R mongodb /datadrive1/mongodb
```

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I can't find any config file on Windows. But I'm am certain that the way I specify the dbpath is correct as when mongod launches it prints out the options it was given, among them, the dbpath and it is correct. I might be mistaken but I think that the dump file MongoDB is looking for is a process memory dump file and is not related  to the database itself. So I don't think the issue is linked to the dbpath.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772428/configuring-mongodb-on-windows Can you try this? You can create your own config file for Windows. Then specify where to look for while starting mongod. I am not sure. But just a thought.