# Mongodb crashes after running for few minutes

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to mongodb. I'm facing a problem while running mongod command. It works fine for few minutes but crashes after few minutes. I don't know why. Here is the error I'm getting:-

```
"msg":"Failed to open minidump file",
"msg":"*** immediate exit due to unhandled exception"
```

I'm using MongoDB shell version v5.0.1

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Try using this command: `mongod --dbpath "path" --repair`

Comment: Is that the only error? seems like it wouldn't be creating a minidump unless something else had already gone wrong.

Comment: @Joe  it also says access denied after this "msg":"Failed to open minidump file"

Comment: Yes, it does report a permission denied while trying to open the minidump file, but why was it try to create a dump in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB minidump file path is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854423/mongodb-minidump-file-path-is-wrong)